# Existence of homomorphism in Modules

Tags: modules

I'm studying projective and injective modules and a serious question raised for me: what is the necessary and sufficient conditions for existence of homomorphisms between modules?

- I mean non-trivial case.
- I know it is very broad question. But at least it might have been
  categorized to some extent.
- Classification is one of the most important things in mathematics so
  it could be an interesting material for research.

Comment: Well there's always the zero homomorphism ... Little more can be said in general

Comment: This is far, far too broad.

Comment: Why too broad? It's a reasonable question to ask and we know how to answer it for vector spaces over a field. So what can we say about modules over other rings?